# Registrar veces que se gana o se pierde e imprimirlas en pantalla

Tags: java

alguien me puede ayudar porfa tengo que hacer un juego de cara o cruz que aleatoriamente de una respuesta y díga si gana o pierde pero necesito que me registre las veces que se gana y se pierde hasta ahora estoy iniciando y no puedo hallar solución esto es lo que tengo lo estoy haciendo bien o hay otra forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon el código como texto por favor, si no haces trabajar de más a quien responda. También te sugiero leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Pon contadores en cada opción y cada vez que entras en un opción haces un contador++. Al final del programa con un System.out.print() muestras los contadores y así ves cuantas veces ganas y cuantas pierdes

Comment: Y por cierto, NO HACE FALTA QUE GRITES :) El código debe ir _como texto, con formato_.

Answer (score 0):

Mira este código que he realizado haciendo unos ajustes a tu ejemplo. He tratado de explicar cada línea con comentarios para que entiendas que estoy haciendo en cada momento:

```
package caracruz;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CaraCruz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Te declaras una variable que se tu saldo para poder jugar xD
        0 = no hay dinero | 1 = hemos metido una moneda para jugar
.       */
        var dinero = 0;
        // Te declaras tu variable para poder leer de la consola
        var sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Me declaro una variable para almancear el random
        var aleatorio = 0;
        // Te decaras una variable para almanecar el lado de la moneda que elige
        // el jugador en cada juego
        var ladoMoneda = "";
        // y te declaras 1 contador para almacenar las veces que gana y pierde
        var numGanadas = 0;
        var numPerdidas = 0;
        // Almacenamos el String cuando se pierde
        var res = "";
        // Ponemos un mensaje de Bienvenida        
        System.out.println("Bievenido al juego de Cara y Cruz");
        System.out.println("Introduce una moneda(1) para poder jugar o para abandonar(0) el juego: ");

        // Si introducemos 1, hemos metido una moneda
        // Si introducimos 0, entonces no podemos seguir jugando
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        dinero = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        while (dinero != 0) { // Con este bucle consigues poder jugar varias veces

            System.out.println("¡Nueva partida!");
            // Solicitamos al jugador que seleccione un lado de la moneda
            System.out.println("¿Qué lado de la moneda eliges, cara o cruz?");
            ladoMoneda = sc.nextLine(); // Guardamos la selección del jugador

            // Hago que con randmon el juego me genere la fortuna, tiramos la moneda
            aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            System.out.println("aleatorio = " + aleatorio);
            switch (dinero) {

                case 1: // A jugar!!!

                    /* Si aleatorio < 50 => ha salido cara y si además se cumple que
                     yo seleccioné cara, hemos ganado 1 e incremento el contador de ganadas
                     Uso equalsIgnoreCase porque compara 2 string ignorando las mayúsculas */
                    if (aleatorio < 50 && ladoMoneda.equalsIgnoreCase("cara")) {
                        System.out.println("Cara, usted gana.");
                        numGanadas++;

                        /* Si aleatorio > 50 => ha salido cruz y si además se cumple que
                     yo seleccioné cruz, hemos ganado 1. 
                     De nuevo hacemos uso de equalsIgnoreCase */
                    } else if (aleatorio > 50 && ladoMoneda.equalsIgnoreCase("cruz")) {
                        System.out.println("Cruz, usted gana.");
                        numGanadas++;

                        // En cualquier otro caso hemos perdido, mostramos el mensaje y sumamos el contador            
                    } else {
                        res = (aleatorio < 50) ? "Cara usted pierde" : "Cruz usted pierde";
                        System.out.println("res = " + res);
                        numPerdidas++;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Llevas jugadas " + (numPerdidas + numGanadas) + " partida(s). ");
                    System.out.println("Has ganado: " + numGanadas + " partidas");
                    System.out.println("Has perdido: " + numPerdidas + " partidas");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Opción incorrecta.");
            }
            // Volvemos a perdirle al jugador si quieres seguir jugando o no
            System.out.println("Si quieres seguir jugando introduce una nueva moneda=1 o salir=0");
            dinero = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        }
        if (dinero == 0) {
            // Si no no hemos metido monedas mostarmos el resultado
            System.out.println("Sentimos que no juegues.");
            System.out.println("Total de partidas jugadas " + (numPerdidas + numGanadas) + ".");
            System.out.println("Has ganado: " + numGanadas + " partidas");
            System.out.println("Has perdido: " + numPerdidas + " partidas");
        }

    }

}
```

y te muestro un ejemplo de salida del progama

```
Bievenido al juego de Cara y Cruz
Introduce una moneda(1) para poder jugar o para abandonar(0) el juego: 
0
Sentimos que no juegues.
Total de partidas jugadas 0.
Has ganado: 0 partidas
Has perdido: 0 partidas
```

o si juegas alguna

```
Bievenido al juego de Cara y Cruz
Introduce una moneda(1) para poder jugar o para abandonar(0) el juego: 
1
¡Nueva partida!
¿Qué lado de la moneda eliges, cara o cruz?
cara
aleatorio = 2
Cara, usted gana.
Llevas jugadas 1 partida(s). 
Has ganado: 1 partidas
Has perdido: 0 partidas
Si quieres seguir jugando introduce una nueva moneda=1 o salir=0
1
¡Nueva partida!
¿Qué lado de la moneda eliges, cara o cruz?
cara
aleatorio = 29
Cara, usted gana.
Llevas jugadas 2 partida(s). 
Has ganado: 2 partidas
Has perdido: 0 partidas
Si quieres seguir jugando introduce una nueva moneda=1 o salir=0
0
Sentimos que no juegues.
Total de partidas jugadas 2.
Has ganado: 2 partidas
Has perdido: 0 partidas
```

Answer (score 0):

Si requieres que la opción sea cara o cruz estamos hablando de un boolean por lo que seria factible usar el método Random nextBoolean ,estableciendo la elección del usuario y la cantidad de veces que quiera lanzar la moneda ,obviamos el porcentaje de 50-50 por que si las veces que salio cara supera a las veces que salio cruz obtienes la opción ganadora todo ello usando un for y un contador. quedaría así

```
import java.util.*;

public class CaraCruz{

public static void main(String[] args) {
Random numAleatorio = new Random();
int contCara=0;
int contCruz=0;
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 

boolean moneda ;
String lado="" ;
int opcion=0;


while(opcion!=2){
System.out.println("Bienvenido al juego de cara o cruz\n");
while(!lado.equals("cara")&&!lado.equals("cruz")){
System.out.println("Elije el lado ganador cara o cruz");
lado=sc.next();
}
System.out.println("Cuantas vecez desea lanzar la moneda?");
int lanzamiento=sc.nextInt();

for (int i=0;i<lanzamiento;i++ ) {
 // Genera un boolean de forma aleatoria
 moneda=numAleatorio.nextBoolean();
 // Si es verdadero cara y sino cruz
if (moneda) {
    contCara++;//cuenta cuantas veces sale cara
} else {
    contCruz++;//cuenta cuantas veces sale cruz
}
}

System.out.println("\nEl numero de veces que salio cara es: "+contCara );
System.out.println("El numero de veces que salio cruz es: "+contCruz );

switch(lado){

case "cara":
if (contCara>contCruz) 
    System.out.println("Felicidades usted ah ganado");
else if(contCara<contCruz)
    System.out.println("Usted ah perdido");
else 
    System.out.println("Empate");
break;

case "cruz":
if (contCruz>contCara) 
    System.out.println("Felicidades usted ah ganado");
else if(contCruz<contCara)
    System.out.println("Usted ah perdido");
else 
    System.out.println("Empate");
break;
default:
 System.out.println("Verifique datos ingresados");

}

System.out.println("quieres volver a Participar? 1(si),2(no)");
opcion=sc.nextInt();
}
}}
```